# Nonexistent images showing up in gmail as "Images are not displayed" when using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

When I receive an email in Gmail via the node Sendgrid Node module, it is marked with `"Images are not displayed. Display images below - Always display images from dan@sweever.com"`. This is weird because there's no image that's supposed to be sent with this email.

My code to send the email is just:

```
const fullEmail = {
      to: 'dan@company.com',
      from: 'Dan at Company <dan@company.com>',
      subject: "Subject",
      text: "Text text text",
    };

return await sgMail.send(fullEmail);
```

Is there a way to go about making Sendgrid emails not send whatever Gmail is interpreting as an image?

Comment: If you still need an answer, this is some kind of "pixel tracking". It allows SendGrid to track if the recipient did open the email